# Adding placeholder settings to presentation details of many items

Tags: presentation, powershell-extensions

I have to add a bunch of placeholder settings to a bunch of items.

These items already have specific presentation details, so not using the standard values.

I tried to add them to standard values, just in case, but didn't change anything as expected.

I moved to PowerShell, but all the scripts I have found so far, show how to add renderings, devices, layouts, but not placeholder settings. Am I missing something on the cmdlet?

I also tried to use the search operations, but it failed while reading the XML...

Any other idea?

As it is now:
[image: As it is]

What I want to achieve

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: you might have another option like disabling Placeholder Setting.
`<setting name="WebEdit.PlaceholdersEditableWithoutSettings" value="true" />`

Comment: When you say placeholder settings, are you talking about `Allowed Controls` in a Placeholder?

Comment: Under presentation details, when you edit a device, you have 3 options: Layout, controls and a placeholder settings. These "placeholder settings" are the entries I want to add.  In the xml, these are p entries. We already have them defined, with different allowed controls for the same key, I "just" need to add the right item here.

Comment: @JihyunI guess, in this case, I don't have the allowed controls, so editors could use any control. Am I right?

Comment: Not sure of the answer to this, but editing these on an item by item basis is a bad idea (and the reason you're having these issues) rather than using Placeholder items and Template overrides... https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/maximizing_usability/posts/the-power-of-placeholder-settings

Comment: @VicentGaliana I was meaning that you don't need to set Placeholder Settings for the controls in the Details if the required placeholder setting for controls makes the problem. However, I'm not much clear on your question, honestly, and this might not be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated the questions with images of the current presentation details, and what I am trying to achieve. As you can see, in the second image, we have several placeholder settings.